# Display YAML in HTML (Trello-style cards)

Tags: html, formatting, yaml

*I have no experience in HTML and got this code from someone else*

I am trying to create a Trello-style task and information list in HTML using YAML to store the data. So far it works fine with when there's just a single item in the content section, but once I try to add a list of items to the content it just displays each one in a line.

Heres the code for the page itself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <!-- CHANGE DESCRIPTION/TITLE HERE  -->
    <meta name="description" content="AnimeKing314's kanban board." />
    <title>Tasks</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../assets/favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.css" />
    <style>
      @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&family=Work+Sans&display=swap);html{font-size:18px;font-family:Poppins,sans-serif}body{background:#fafafa;color:#121212}main{margin-bottom:3rem}h1,h2,h3,h4{font-family:'Work Sans',sans-serif;text-align:center}section{overflow:auto hidden;white-space:nowrap}h2{border-top:1px solid #111;border-bottom:1px solid #111;padding:.5rem 0;margin:.5rem 0}section{margin-bottom:1rem;text-align:center}section>div{height:500px;width:300px;height:100%;display:inline-block;margin:.5em 1em;background:#eee;box-shadow:0 0 4px #888;padding:1em;border-radius:4px}h3{border-bottom:1px solid #111;padding-bottom:.5em;margin-bottom:.5em}article{height:500px;overflow:hidden auto;white-space:normal}article div.card{margin:.3rem;padding:.3rem;background:#fafafa;box-shadow:0 0 2px #888;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:4px}article div.card h4{font-size:1rem;font-weight:700;text-align:left;margin:0}article div.card p{font-size:.8rem;margin:.5em 0;text-align:left}#overlay{text-align:center;position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;padding:5em;background-color:#fafafa}#nsfw-confirm{display:inline-block;background:#d100d1;color:#fff;font-weight:700;padding:.2em 1em;cursor:pointer;margin-top:2em;box-shadow:0 0 4px #888}#nsfw-confirm:hover{text-decoration:none;background-color:purple;box-shadow:0 0 2px #888}
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <!-- CHANGE HEADING HERE  -->
  <h1>Parallel Worlds of Lust Task Management</h1>

  <main>
      
      <section id="tasks">
        <h2>Tasks</h2>
        <div id="todo">
            <h3>To Do</h3>
            <article></article>
        </div>
        <div id="doing">
            <h3>Doing</h3>
            <article></article>
        </div>
        <div id="done">
            <h3>Done</h3>
            <article></article>
        </div>
        <div id="on-hold">
            <h3>On Hold</h3>
            <article></article>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="other">
        <h2>Other</h2>
        <div id="universe-list">
            <h3>Universe List</h3>
            <article></article>
        </div>
      </section>
  </main>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.js" data-cfasync="false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/nodeca/js-yaml/dist/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    !function(){
      "use strict";
      $(document).on(":loaded",function(e){
        Object.keys(e.tasks).forEach(function(t){
          var n,a=e.tasks[t];a&&a.length&&$((n=t,n+" article")).append(a.map(function(e){
            return t=e.title,n=e.content,$(document.createElement("div")).addClass("card").append([$(document.createElement("h4")).append(t),$(document.createElement("p")).append(n)]);var t,n
          }))
        })
      })
    }();
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    !function(){
      "use strict";
      $(function(){
        $.ajax("tasks.txt",{
          dataType:"text",success:function(t){
            $(document).trigger({
              type:":loaded",tasks:jsyaml.load(t)
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the YAML document (for structure):

```yaml
"#todo":
  - title: Art
    content: Make art for all intro scenes.
  - title: Setup Code
    content: Adding all the necessary background code. Still left is Cheat menu, Sandbox screens.

"#doing":
  - title: Character Models
    content: Find/make koikatsu character models for all intro characters.
  - title: Script Intro
    content: Complete the intro of the story (up to start of sandbox).

"#done":


"#on-hold":


"#universe-list":
  - title: Pokemon
    content:
      - Misty
  - title: DoA
    content:
      - Kasumi
  - title: Gate, Thus the JSDF Fought There
    content:
      - Rory Mercury
  - title: Railgun
    content:
      - Misaka
      - Misaki
      - Uiharu
      - Kuroko
      - Saten
  - title: Main Universe
    content:
      - MC
      - Little Sister
      - Mother
      - Jane
      - Emma
      - Tom
  - title: Edge Universe
    content:
      - Quest Giving Girl, Name TBD
```

The problem comes in the universe-list. Instead of showing as (for example):

## Railgun

- Misaka
- Misaki
- etc

it shows as:

## Railgun

MisakaMisakietc

Answer (score 1):

I found that I can add html tags to the content of the yaml document. Something like this:

```yaml
- title: Main Universe
    content:
      - <li>MC</li>
      - <li>Little Sister</li>
      - <li>Mother</li>
```